# remove the text in the price in single page woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

Can you help me? i have been adding some custom codes in woocommerce/product page in my functions.php file. i have a 0 price on the product but it shows a free text on the product list shop page. when i added this code

```
function woo_my_custom_free_message() {
    return "This product is FREE!";
}

add_filter('woocommerce_free_price_html', 'woo_my_custom_free_message');
```

when i hover the products on the shop page it shows that the text is free and i liked it. but if you will click the product of that free text, it also shows the free text that i added in the code on my functions. php. my idea is to delete that text, but if i hide the price on css, all the prices will be gone. that is the last problem i have.

guys please help me.
thank you in advance. you guys are awesome! :D

[image]

Comment: what do you mean? i just want to delete the same text that is in the product page in the single product page :)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal there's nothing wrong with the filter...

Comment: im sorry bro but it still shows the text. here is the link that i was talking about

https://breakingfreeindustries-touma08.c9users.io/product/to-build-a-greater-social-life/

Comment: Ooops! I supposed to be javascript. sorry.

Comment: its ok @BhojendraNepal. thank you for helping out. :)

Comment: @hilarion is that all your code for function `woo_my_custom_free_message`? I can see in your site that it's not.. please add all what's inside it so I can give proper solution...

Comment: @Reigel thank you for helping me but yes, this is all the code for function. this is the code from this link that i copied.

https://gist.github.com/corsonr/6112412

i just want to delete the text in the single product page. thanks bro!

Comment: @hilarion please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the right way to do it.

```
function woo_my_custom_free_message($price) {

    $price = is_product()?'':'This product is FREE!';
    return $price;

}
add_filter('woocommerce_free_price_html', 'woo_my_custom_free_message', 10, 1);
```

Comment: almost bro. it didn't work. but the code you gave me removed the text in the single product. but also the texts in the product lists.

this is the link for the product lists. 
https://breakingfreeindustries-touma08.c9users.io/product-list-2/

this is the link example of a single product.
https://breakingfreeindustries-touma08.c9users.io/product/to-build-a-greater-social-life/

Thank you bro. you really are an awesome person :)

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Also Use:**

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price' );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price' );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price' );
    function hide_free_price($price){
    return 'This product is FREE!';
    }
```